# how to fix " You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system. Users in groups 'adm', 'systemd-journal' can see all messages."

Tags: mssql

I am trying to install ms sql `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup` on ubuntu but gwtting this messsage i have tried it the following `sudo usermod -aG adm <username>` and `sudo usermod -aG systemd-journal <username>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you rebooted/reopened a new shell? What Ubuntu version is that?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
su root -l -c "adduser <user> adm"
su root -l -c "adduser <user> systemd-journal"
```

Then logout and login or reboot or run `systemctl daemon-reload`. One of these will hopefully work.